# What does “forbiddenNameValidator(new RegExp(this.forbiddenName, 'i'))(control)” do?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm a java developer and a new baby in Angular. I'm a little bit confused about the Typescript syntax.

I'm reading this [article](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-to-template-driven-forms), specifically "Custom validators" and this snippet

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appForbiddenName]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: ForbiddenValidatorDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class ForbiddenValidatorDirective implements Validator {
  @Input('appForbiddenName') forbiddenName: string;

  validate(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null {
    return this.forbiddenName ? forbiddenNameValidator(new RegExp(this.forbiddenName, 'i'))(control)
                              : null;
  }
}
```

and the definition of forbiddenNameValidator function is:

```
export function forbiddenNameValidator(nameRe: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
    const forbidden = nameRe.test(control.value);
    return forbidden ? {forbiddenName: {value: control.value}} : null;
  };
}
```

what is the translation of **forbiddenNameValidator(new RegExp(this.forbiddenName, 'i'))(control)**?

Comment: What do you mean *"translation"*? It's calling the function with a regex, which is constructed with two arguments, then calls the function returned by the first function with the control.

Answer (score 1):

If the value `this.forbiddenName` is falsy (`false, null, undefined, 0, false`), then it will return null, otherwise it will call the function `forbiddenNameValidator` with the given `regex`. The `i` in the parameter for `RegExp` is for making the regex `case-insensitive`.

Answer (score 0):

it was weird for me, but you can do things like this

```
export function f1(param1) {
  return (param2) => {
      return (param3) => {
        console.log(param1, param2, param3);
      };
  };
}
```

then call the function like this

```
f1(1)(2)(3);
```